# SQL Update Table with Sum Results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two Tables ("Shortages", "Orders"). Shortages contains each Material once, Orders is all the Material orders. I am trying to update Shortages field CurrentWeek with the sum of all orders of a material from Orders.

I am not an SQL guru and this is stumping me. I have googled things but I can't seem to get anything to work.

I can write a select query that gets me what I want with all the `WHERE` clauses but I can't get the values into the other table.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us what code you have tried. That will help us in having a basis for giving a response.

Comment: `SELECT Orders.Material, Sum(Orders.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity FROM Orders WHERE (((Orders.Plant)="N.Amer") AND ((Left([Orders].[Order_Number],4))<>"NA01") AND ((Year([Ship_Date])*53+DatePart("ww",[Ship_Date]))=Year(Date())*53+DatePart("ww"‌​,Date()))) GROUP BY Orders.Material;` That is the select query I have that gives me what I want and groups it...I am trying to pass that grouped sums to the Shortages table...Material is the link between both tables. I will try a few more and see what I can post.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
UPDATE Shortages
   SET CurrentWeek = (SELECT SUM(quantity)
                        FROM Orders
                       WHERE Orders.Material = Shortages.Material
                         AND <which records in Orders count toward the current Shortages record>)
 WHERE <which records in Shortages you want to update>
```

Obviously you'll need to modify it with the proper column names.

Comment: you may also need to do additional filtering in the where to limit it to the "current week"

Comment: Okay I tried
`Update Shortages
    Set CurrentWeek=(SELECT Orders.Material, Sum(Orders.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity
FROM Orders
WHERE (((Orders.Plant)="N.Amer") And ((Left(Orders.Order_Number,4))<>"NA01") And ((Year([Ship_Date])*53+DatePart("ww",[Ship_Date]))=Year(Date())*53+DatePart("ww",Date())))
GROUP BY Orders.Material)`
But now I am being told I have "written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's from clause." It may be worth noting that at this moment I am utilizing Microsoft Access (if that helps).

Comment: As it says, you can only have one column in your subquery.  In the inner select you specified `Orders.Material, Sum(Orders.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity`, which is two columns. The `UPDATE` statement works differently than you think: while it does update ALL records, the statement itself defines how to modify EACH record.  Basically: for each record in Shortages set the CurrentWeek column to this value. The subquery must return a single value, which is why above I limited it with `WHERE` to filter it down to "one" material, i.e. "the material for the current row being updated", Shortages.Material

Comment: more like this: `Update Shortages Set CurrentWeek=(SELECT Sum(Orders.Quantity) FROM Orders  WHERE (((Orders.Plant)="N.Amer") And ((Left(Orders.Order_Number,4))<>"NA01")   And ((Year([Ship_Date])*53+DatePart("ww",[Ship_Date]))=Year(Date())*53+DatePart("ww"‌​,Date()))) and Orders.Material = Shortages.Material)` Also, some of those criteria might need to be in the Where clause of the `UPDATE` statement, not the subquery. I've updated my answer with more syntax

Comment: Plaid trying it now, I greatly appreciate that explanation it made sense!

Answer (score 0):

Get the `SUM()` first and then perform an update join. Something like below (** It's a demo query but hope you understood the point)

```
update Shortages s
join (
select orderid, sum(order_qty) as total_qty
from orders
group by orderid ) xxx on s.orderid = xxx.orderid
set s.CurrentWeek = xxx.total_qty;
```